# Is there possible way to get data sampling in continous data batches?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We've a data stream with continously dumps data in our data lake. Is there a good solution with min running to get 10% random data samples from the data?

I'm currently using code(snipped below) but this will outgrow 10% total sampling as new batches will arrive. I've also tried to calculate 10 batches of 100 records each with (.1) mean but it resulted in ~32% sampling.

```
select id,
(uniform(0::float, 1::float, random(1)) < .10)::boolean as sampling
from temp_hh_mstr;
```

Prior to it, I thought to get sampling via snowflake's TABLESAMPLE by substracting from the total count and current IDs in sampling from the table. It takes calculations for every time and any batch arrives which will increase the cost.

Some additional referece I've been thinking towards -

- [Wilson Score Interval With Continuity Correction](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=binomial%20confidence%20interval&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22WilsonScoreIntervalWithContinuityCorrection%22%2C%20%22phat%22%7D%20-%3E%220.1%22&assumption=%22FSelect%22%20-%3E%20%7B%7B%22BinomialInterval%22%7D%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22WilsonScoreIntervalWithContinuityCorrection%22%2C%20%22c%22%7D%20-%3E%220.95%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22WilsonScoreIntervalWithContinuityCorrection%22%2C%20%22n%22%7D%20-%3E%22100%22)
- [Binomial Confidence Interval](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=binomial%20confidence%20interval&assumption=%22FSelect%22%20-%3E%20%7B%7B%22WilsonScoreIntervalWithContinuityCorrection%22%7D%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22BinomialInterval%22%2C%20%22phat%22%7D%20-%3E%220.1%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22BinomialInterval%22%2C%20%22c%22%7D%20-%3E%220.95%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22BinomialInterval%22%2C%20%22n%22%7D%20-%3E%22100%22)

Comment: Hi - do you mean a 10% sample of the entire table or a 10% sample of a subset of the data? If you mean a subset, how do you define the subset (by timestamp loaded or something else)?

Comment: Hi @NickW -  10% of delta records which eventually turned up as 10% of entire table. Subset we get to know by delta records currently gathered from upstream system by running the batch.

Comment: Ok, but how do you know which records are from the latest batch once that batch has been loaded into the Snowflake table, which is where you want to run the sampling? Why can't you sample the subset in the table by using a WHERE clause that selects just the subset you require?

Comment: @NickW -  I'm doing operation delta records is merged with a WHERE clause on timestamp. The issue is sampling is not exactly 10% and growing more as new batches arriving.

Comment: I’m afraid I don’t understand the issue you are facing. My understanding is that you want to sample 10% of the last batch loaded into your table. What is stopping you selecting just the records loaded in the last batch and sampling them?

Comment: @NickW - My issue is sampling 10% of entire table growing to ~32% for entire table as new batches are getting into system. It should always be 10%, right?  I've tried both the scenarios for sampling from temporary table created by delta records then merging back to main table; also, merging directly to main table and sampling based on where clause. Both the scenarios are not yielding correct results. One thing I've noted that if data size is very low (say 20-30) records then sampling move towards 50% sample rate even with (.10) mean. I'm not getting is also.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246581/discussion-between-nickw-and-vaibhav).